# iOS MDM vendor signing process

Tags: ios, mdm

I followed the instruction of the MDM vendor signing document http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning. In step 2, it needs you to create a certificate from iOS Provisioning Portal. You need to click the "other" tab on the center. In my portal, there are only four tabs but no "other" tab. Do I miss anything? Please help.